# OpenLDAP - where is my slapd.conf?

Tags: ubuntu, openldap

I have installed OpenLDAP on Unbuntu 10.04.
I wanted to configure my ldap but I can't find **slapd.conf** in `/etc/ldap/`
In this directory there is a **ldap.conf** but seems not to be the same.

How can I configure my ldap ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You will need to use the new `cn=config` configuration method, where the LDAP server will be configured via a separate data tree in the directory (which is usually represented as LDIF files under `/etc/ldap/slapd.d`.

Answer (score 6):

OpenLDAP uses a separate directory which contains the cn=config Directory Information Tree (DIT) (formerly slapd.conf). The cn=config DIT is used to dynamically configure the slapd daemon, allowing the modification of schema definitions, indexes, ACLs, etc without stopping the service.

See: https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/openldap-server.html and http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/ch6/slapd-config.html

Answer (score 0):

I found this path `/usr/local/etc/openldap/slapd.conf` on the freebsd website:

[Configuring OpenLDAP](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/articles/ldap-auth/ldap.html)